# Redirecting the output of program which itself is an argument

Tags: linux, bash

Let me present the scenario first with the command which is not working under linux bash environment.

```
$ timed-run prog1 1>/dev/null 2>out.tmp
```

Here in the above case I want to redirect the output of program 'prog1' to /dev/null and out.tmp file. But this command is redirecting the output (if any) of timed-run to out.tmp.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

From a simple example, I experience exactly the opposite.

```
$ time ls 1> foo 2> bar

real    0m0.002s
user    0m0.004s
sys     0m0.000s
$ more foo
<show files>
$ more bar
<empty>
$
```

The output of ls is redirected, and the output of time is not!

Comment: Thanks alot for the answer. But I want 1 as well as 2 to be attached with ls only.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is in timed-run not in bash.  If you run the same command replacing timed-run with the standard time command this works as you expect.  Mainly timed run needs to run the arguments of prog1 through the shell again.  If it is a shell script you can do this with the eval command.  For example:

```
#!/bin/sh

echo here is some output
echo $*
eval $*
```

now run

```
timed-run prog1 '1>/dev/null' '2>output.tmp'
```

Comment: Actually I missed one thing that there is an argument after timed-run too. i.e $ timed-run 20 prog1 1>/dev/null and 2>out.tmp. And I want 1 and 2 both to be redirected for prog1 instead of timed-run

Comment: Yes in fact time is working fine as expected but timed-run is also a script from expect package. Are there any suggestion for how to tackle this situation as I want a timed run of the executable i.e prog1

Comment: In this case assuming that the 20 is an argument to timed-run then you just need to remove it from $* in my example

Comment: I would expect that you would need to grab the args in expect and run it in a bash subshell, but I have only ever written 2-3 expect scripts, so I would not know how off hand.

Answer (score 0):

How about using `sh -c 'cmd'` like so:

```
    time -p sh -c 'ls -l xcvb 1>/dev/null 2>out.tmp'
    time -p sh -c 'exec 0</dev/null 1>/dev/null 2>out.tmp; ls -l xcvb'

    # in out.tmp:
    # ls: xcvb: No such file or directory
```